# How can I play a FLV file in Windows Media Player?

Tags: video, flash, windows-media-player, codec, thumbnails

I'd like to play Flash video or "FLV" files in Windows Media Player. I've done this before using codec packs like K-Lite and CCCP, but I've found they cause too many problems and I'd really like to avoid these.

I've also seen [PlayFLV](http://www.playflv.com/), but this pre-dates Flash support for H.264 and that's kinda required these days.

So are there other codec options available? Ideally there would also be thumbnail support with the codec.

NB: Using another video player is **not** an option to me -- I like WMP, I just want to know the best codec for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try [ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/) - Media player may still give you an error, but it should play the file with no problem. Also, are you positive media player is completely updated?

Answer (score 4):

if you must use WMP, then you'll likely have to install the codecs for it. I strongly suggest using VLC player, it just updated to 1.0 and has always worked for me with .flvs

Comment: I know I'll need to install a codec, but which one is best is the idea of the question. Also, I really don't like VLC -- I've had way to many stability issues with it over the years, the UI is ugly, and the default video scaling technique doesn't even do smoothing.

Comment: If VLC isn't your cup of tea, try MPC - Media Player Classic.  It has all the functionality of VLC in the old WMP skin.

Comment: I've used that too -- the interface is also ugly as sin, and just like VLC it doesn't support my media keys. I like WMP, switching to another player is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bare minimum would be [ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/), plus the appropriate splitter:

- FLV => [Gabest's FLV Splitter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/files/)
- MP4 => [Haali Media Splitter](http://haali.cs.msu.ru/mkv/)

However, I should warn that installing those three is pretty much the same thing as installing CCCP, the only other things it includes are VSFilter and a couple minor codecs (WavPack/MPEG2).