# FLV codec for Windows Media Player?

Tags: windows-media-player, codec

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I play a FLV file in Windows Media Player?](https://superuser.com/questions/11693/how-can-i-play-a-flv-file-in-windows-media-player)

What I want is a FLV codec for WMP 12, on Windows 7 Professional x64, that's it.

I'm really happy how it plays mp4s so I don't want to mess up anything, just a clean codec from a trustworthy source.

P.S. I just switched from VLC to WMP after I noticed the huge difference on CPU usage.

Answer (score 0):

Install a codec pack. [This](http://www.windows7codecs.com/) one is the best codec packs out there. You can also choose from which codecs to pick.